# getting null pointer exception when executing query in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, parent-child, jdo

i am using google app engine with gwt. 
i have two class question and vote when i am accessing vote by querying on question it gives me null pointer exception.

my class are as follows
Question

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION,table="question")
public class Question implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6355873282541087204L;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    private String title;

    @Persistent(dependent="true")
    private Vote vote;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Vote getVote() {
        return vote;
    }

    public void setVote(Vote vote) {
        this.vote = vote;
    }

}
```

Vote

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION,table="vote")
public class Vote implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1331159194642997258L;

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    private int like;

    @Persistent
    private int unlike;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getLike() {
        return like;
    }

    public void setLike(int like) {
        this.like = like;
    }

    public int getUnlike() {
        return unlike;
    }

    public void setUnlike(int unlike) {
        this.unlike = unlike;
    }

}
```

my code in serverImpl class

```
@Override
public List<QuestionDTO> viewAllQuestion() {

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Query query = pm.newQuery(Question.class);

    List<Question> list=null;
    try{
        list = (List<Question>) query.execute();
    }finally{
        pm.close();
    }

    List<QuestionDTO> questionDtoList = new ArrayList<QuestionDTO>();

    for(Question question : list){
        QuestionDTO questionDTO = new QuestionDTO();
        questionDTO.setId(question.getId());
        questionDTO.setTitle(question.getTitle());

        VoteDTO voteDTO = new VoteDTO();
        voteDTO.setId(question.getVote().getId());
        voteDTO.setLike(question.getVote().getLike());
        voteDTO.setUnlike(question.getVote().getLike());            
        questionDTO.setVoteDTO(voteDTO);            

        questionDtoList.add(questionDTO);
    }

    return questionDtoList;
}
```

error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.wa.jdocascadedemo.server.impl.QuestionServiceImpl.viewAllQuestion(QuestionServiceImpl.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 22 more
```

where i am wrong ?
thanks in advance

Comment: So an NPE in *your own code*, at some line that you don't identify?

Comment: i got null pointer exception at `question.getVote()` line but i don't understand why it comes null.

Comment: As mentioned on the other question you raised, you can easily look at the log when you retrieve your objects, and look at lifecycle state etc etc.

Comment: is that any problem with uni-directional relationship when we query on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my mistake. i have not assign defaultFetchGroup = "true" to object of Vote class in Question class. 
it is necessary to defaultFetchGroup = "true" When a persisted object is retrieved from the datastore.

Comment: Or put the field of that class in the "fetch plan", see JDO spec and DN docs.